# how to write below sql query with all mentioned conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using java/oracle. i have below issue.

```
SELECT
         DISTINCT id_one,
         status 
     FROM
         sometable 
     WHERE
         id_two IN (
             SELECT
                 DISTINCT id_two  
             FROM
                 othertable
         ) 
         AND id_one IN (1946,1948,1949)
```

i have above query to fetch data from one table. inner query's data from other table.
now i need add one where condition to inner query. 
othertable has one more field called name.

these are the ids that i mentioned: 1946,1948,1949. here each id will have names as below: name1, name2, name3
name1, name2, name3 are passed from java application.

finally the query that i need as follows.

```
SELECT
         DISTINCT id_one,
         status 
     FROM
         sometable 
     WHERE
         id_two IN (
             SELECT
                 DISTINCT id_two  
             FROM
                 othertable other where other.name in('name1','name2','name3')
         ) 
         AND id_one IN (1946,1948,1949)
```

my questions is: **for 1946 id name1 should be considered and for 1948 id name2 should be considered**
**and for 1949 id name3 should be considered as criteria.** i mean query should not consider all 3 names for every id.

how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also be done like in the following way:

```
select distinct s.id_one, s.status
  from sometable s join othertable o on (s.id_two = o.id_two)
 where (s.id_one = 1946 and o.name = 'name1')
    OR (s.id_one = 1948 and o.name = 'name2')
    OR (s.id_one = 1949 and o.name = 'name3');
```

Comment: Sorry, i have edited my question. name1,name2 and name3 are not columns they are values fired against name column of othertable.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for your quick reply. i have a doubt. in my query i placed IN (1946,1948,1949) . here number of ids are dynamic in the example i gave there are 3 Ids, some times there can be 10...in that case how can i handle? select 1946, status from sometable where id_two in is not possible in case of dynamic nature. Please help.

Comment: I edited my answer once again. This should be more suitable for dynamic nature of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

From doc: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_one, status 
FROM sometable 
WHERE 
 id_two IN ( 
   SELECT DISTINCT id_two
   FROM othertable other 
   where ( other.name, id_one )  in (
       select 'name1',1946 from dual union all
       select 'name2',1948 from dual union all
       select 'name3',1949 from dual )
  )
```

Comment: Sorry, i have edited my question. name1,name2 and name3 are not columns they are values fired against name column of othertable.